# how can we dynamically add only 20 images from webservice in the grid view

Tags: android

I want 20 images on one page and upon clicking on the next button, I will get another images on the same page.
That means, like in email programs, we have "older" & "oldest" by clicking "older" we will get the next emails.
same way i want images here by XML Parser.

```
GridView gView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
btnPrevious = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);
gView.setAdapter(adap);

btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        adap.notifydatasetchanged();/*asking for create notifydatasetchanged()*/

        EfficientAdapter adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);/* shows the error and asking for create constructor  EfficientAdapter(OnClickListener)*/
        gView.setAdapter(adap);
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want somebody to write the whole program for you?

Comment: From what I have understood you need to have a variable say counter, increment it while adding the images to the grid,once that count is 20 stop adding them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply..will u please help me by showing me some code??

Comment: Post any code that you have written so far.

Comment: Can you please edit this for clarity and post example code? I don't quite see a question here.

Comment: as you told me, i have attached the code in my question.Please refer n reply me soon.

Comment: @Saurabh - Thanks, that's a lot better and should help get you answers.

Answer (score 0):

First and above all if you want to parse all the images from XML together at at time and show them, It will be a bed approach , Instead let your server file handle this i.e. each time you hit a url it should return you 20 records .
For example

```
String urlToHit=Config.basicUrl+"serverfile.php?showperpage="+Config.showPerPage+"&pageindex="+Config.currentPage;
```

where showPerPage is the number of records you want in per page and currentPage is the index of the page (it will be incremented for each new page).
Now suppose you have a **button** and now **onClick of button** parse the url(hit the url) and call setAdapter:

```
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
```

and **return 20 by getCount()** of your BaseAdapter.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: if we will return 20 by getCount() then how it would know after clicking next button should start from 21.

Comment: Each time when you will hit the url, it will return you next 20 records as you are passing the current page with the url.you just need to parse and show it.

Comment: For this you have to write codes mannually in your backend file(CMS) which is returning you the xml.Thats not your task , its for the one who is developing CMS(files on server which returns XML) for your app.

Comment: ya, they made URL in which we have to pass page no. and limit. So we can get data from webservice basis of limit.

Comment: yes thats the proper way to do this . you just need to hit the specific url each time user click on the load more button and parse the the data and show it in gridview using setAdapter.

Comment: you mean to say whenever we click on next button then at each time we will call xmlparser?

Comment: **yes**  and each time we set the adapter .

Comment: but i m trying then it is showing error at object is getting data from helper class...

Comment: can you edit the above posted code to let me know what exactly  you are doing .

Comment: https://gist.github.com/934176 please go through this link you will get whole activity....

Comment: you should accept the answer if you thinks its helpful for you...:)

Answer (score 0):

The error you mark in the code (`EfficientAdapter adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);`) is because `this`, in the context of that callback, refers to the `new OnClickListener`, instead of the view.

You can either create a new one as `EfficientAdapter adap = new EfficientAdapter(v);` or, much better, reuse the one you created before:

Remove the two lines

```
   EfficientAdapter adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);/* shows the error and asking for create constructor  EfficientAdapter(OnClickListener)*/
    gView.setAdapter(adap);
```

and use the onClick callBack to ask the server for the next 20 images. Fill those images to your adapter and then `adap.notifyDataSetChanged()` (mind the **Caps**) "Notifies the attached View that the underlying data has been changed and it should refresh itself."

Comment: Aleadam have u any sample code for that...?? or edit the above given code...it will be more beneficial to understand your idea...